# How can i stop this cell from doubling its height?

Tags: html, css, cell, htmltidy

Ok so I have begun changing my pages to CSS so I can link to style sheets for all their benefits.

The page will get run through html tidy from w3 after all the incompatible bits are altered to css.

[Html tidy](http://www.w3.org/People/Raggett/tidy/)

After adding some css instead of the incompatible html i had before that doesnt come out good through html tidy the cells are twice their height.

Here's a [link to the page](http://www.techagesite.com/new_page_9.htm) in progress:

and here is one of the cells in questions code:

```
<td style="width: 283px; height: 30px; 
    background-image: url('EmuNewNGd_Template/techage_map1_featurebar.jpg')">
   <p align="center">
       <b>
          <font color="#000080" size="2" face="Tahoma">
            Bringing You Nothing But The Best
         </font>
      </b>
   </p>
</td>
```

any ideas why they are so big because their size when viewed in a browser is not 30px but much larger.

Keep in mind that I'm not very good with CSS.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are bigger because there are `<p>` elements in the table which contain the text. By default `<p>` elements have a margin. You can remove that by adding this to your css:

`#AutoNumber9 tbody tr td p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}`

This is specific only for the table with the id #AutoNumber9.
If you want to do that for all `<p>` elements on the site you can add:

```
p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```